# Append to global variable inside a loop?

Tags: bash

I have a global variable `$EMAIL`. I want to loop through several files and for each that meets a criteria I will add it to `$EMAIL` for report generation.

The problem is when I redefine `$EMAIL` inside the loop it only changes `$EMAIL` at the scope of the loop iteration. The global version of `$EMAIL` remains empty.

*This is a simplified version of my program:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

EMAIL="I echo without 'nope'"
ls | while read line; do
  if [ 73523 -lt 86400 ]
  then
    echo "Hasn't been backed up in over a day"
    EMAIL="$EMAIL nope"
  fi
done

echo $EMAIL
```

How can I modify my script so that I can add to `$EMAIL` from inside the loop?

---

***Edit/Update***

I wanted to further simplify the example so I tried changing

```
ls | while read line; do
```

to:

```
for i in {1..2}; do
```

Strangely with this change `nope` is appended to `$EMAIL`, maybe I'm misunderstanding what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

`bash` run `cmd2` in a subshell, so changing variable won't be visible to parent shell.

You can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

EMAIL="I echo without 'nope'"
while read line; do
  if [ 73523 -lt 86400 ]
  then
    echo "Hasn't been backed up in over a day"
    EMAIL="$EMAIL nope"
  fi
done < <(ls)

echo "$EMAIL"
```

or using `zsh` or `ksh`, which will run `cmd2` in the same shell process.

Answer (score 3):

@cuonglm has the answer to your question. However your *problem* is parsing the output of `ls`. You should do this:

```
email="..."
for file in *; do
    t=$(calculate_last_backup "$file")
    if some_condition_with "$t"; then
        email+="some text"
    fi
done
do_something_with "$email"
```

- [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- Don't use ALL_CAPS_VAR_NAMES
- [Always quote your `"$variables"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)
- in bash, append to a variable with `+=`